# how to get the salty taste out of your cupcake

Tags: cupcakes

I was making cupcakes from scratch with my kids and I tasted the batter after we mixed everything into it .The batter was really really good but it tasted really salty.We tried adding milk but it didn't REALLY help it!Do u have any ideas?

Comment: How much salt did you put in? Many recipes call for about a pinch for a decent batch, I prefer none at all. Your options are dilute by making another quantity (or 2 or 3) without salt and mixing (assuming it's not baked) or start again, but without knowing how bad, it's hard to tell. Uncooked baking powder can taste a little salty but probably not enough.

Comment: The question is what flavors complement salty batter... caramel?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a combination of salt and baking powder. Sometimes people can't put their finger on it so the say salt when it is too much baking powder.